# Integrable functions and their inverses

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is the following statement true?

> Let $f(x)$ be an integrable function on $[a,b]$. Suppose $|f(x)| \geq 1$ on $[a,b]$.  Then, $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is also integrable on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check two things:

1. $x\mapsto\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is measurable.
2. $\int_a^b\lvert\frac{1}{f(x)}\lvert dx<\infty$

**Hints:**

1. What do you know about the measurability of $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$. What about the composition of measurable functions?
2. $\int_a^b\lvert\frac{1}{f(x)}\lvert dx\leq (b-a)\sup_{x\in [a,b]}\lvert\frac{1}{f(x)}\lvert$